# Is there an option to show gtest case run/result in one line?

Tags: c++, googletest

I don't want to see duplicate names exploring scenarios (especially confusing when there are a lot of tests).

```
Default:                                         Wish:
[ RUN      ] Help.I_need_somebody                [ RUN   OK ] Help.I_need_somebody (0 ms)        
[       OK ] Help.I_need_somebody (0 ms)         [ RUN   OK ] Help.not_just_anybody (0 ms)       
[ RUN      ] Help.not_just_anybody               [ RUN   OK ] Help.you_know_I_need_someone (0 ms)
[       OK ] Help.not_just_anybody (0 ms)        [ RUN   OK ] Help.Help (0 ms)                   
[ RUN      ] Help.you_know_I_need_someone        
[       OK ] Help.you_know_I_need_someone (0 ms) 
[ RUN      ] Help.Help                           
[       OK ] Help.Help (0 ms)
```

Any tips?

Comment: where would the output of the tests appear?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without wrapping the gtest runner in your own script that will parse gtest output and convert it to format you like.

Comment: The split allows to spot the problematic test in case of hard error (as segfault). or to have display in UT.